# Can I have $(RM) $(PREFIX)/bin/$(PROGS) as a make uninstall target somehow?

Tags: makefile, uninstallation

I realize why what I have is not working since `PROGS     = ltest makefiletest` making `$(PREFIX)/ltest` be removed together with `makefiletest` from the local directory.

Is there a way to do this in a one-liner or do I have to specify all targets one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addprefix function is designed for this exact use case:

```
$(RM) $(addprefix $(PREFIX)/bin/,$(PROGS))
```

Comment: Excellent I could not find that googeling... Thanks!